# How to load images asynchronously on iPad 3 in jquery TableSorter?

Tags: jquery, ios, ipad, asynchronous, tablesorter

This is a very specific problem that I'm not expecting anyone to have an answer to, but perhaps someone has tried to do exactly what I'm doing and knows what the problem is.

Basically, I'm taking an ID and loading a series of images into a jquery TableSorter gridview cell using an asynchronous file handler in ASP.NET.  I'm using the file handler on nearly every page in the project, and it works fine (including instances where I'm loading a single image into a gridview cell).  It also works fine on every desktop browser I've tested it on and on all browsers on my Android device.

Likewise, it also works for the iPad on every page except for the page in question.  The difference is that I'm creating the elements dynamically in the TableSorter Initialized event on the page in this case:

```
.... initialized: function(table){
        $("#items tr td[id^=imagepreview").each(function () {
            var orderid = $(this).attr("id").replace("imagepreview", "");

            $.ajax({
                type: "GET",
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                url: "../FRED.asmx/GetOrderItemsByOrderID?OrderID=" + orderid,
                dataType: "json",
                success: function (data) {
                    $.map(data.d, function (item) {
                        if (item.IsPickup != true) {

                            $("#imagepreview" + orderid).html($("#imagepreview" + orderid).html() + "<img src=\"../AsyncImage.ashx?ImageType=TN&ID=" + item.ItemID + "\" class=\"tnimage\" width=\"100px\" height=\"75px\" onclick=\"prepareImage(" + item.ItemID + ");return false;\" title=\"" + item.Name + "\" data-toggle=\"modal\"  style=\"cursor: pointer;\" data-target=\"#picModal\"/>");

                        }
                    });
                }
            });
        });
    } ....
```

The resulting code on the page looks like this:

```
<td id="imagepreview114"></td>
```

The other pages that work properly look like this and are inside of an ASP.NET repeater control:

```
<td>
    <img src='../AsyncImage.ashx?ImageType=TN&ID=<%#Eval("ItemID") %>' class="tnimage"
     width="100px" height="75px" onclick="prepareImage(<%#Eval("ItemID") %>);return false;"
     data-id='<%#Eval("ItemID") %>' data-name='<%#Eval("Title") %>' data-desc='<%#Eval("Description") %>'
      data-quan='<%#Eval("Quantity") %>' data-target="#editImage" data-toggle="modal" /></td>
```

...which is what the code should look like, minus the server code of course.

I know it has something to do with this code, but as I said, this works fine on desktop browsers and every Android device I've tried.

The easiest solution at this point would just be to buy them all $30 Android tabs instead of the iPads they have now, but of course I'd prefer a viable code solution.

I wish I could debug it, but I tried Firebug Lite (which is no help b/c it's a bookmarklet that won't catch anything that happens on page load), and I don't have a Mac, so I can't use Web Inspector.

Thanks!

Comment: Did you check the contents of `data` in the success function on the iPad? So, if I understand correctly, the iPad3 is the *only* tablet that the code doesn't work on? Why use tablesorter? Are you sorting the images? How do you know when a image is ready to view? Inside the success function are you updating tablesorter to push the new data to its cache? Lastly, are you using a custom parser for sorting?

Comment: The iPad 3 is the only tablet I've tested it on personally.  The guys I'm developing for all have iPad 4's.  I've tested it on two Android tablets and a phone, and they all work fine.  Firefox, Chrome, IE all work on the desktop.

I'm using tablesorter b/c I do need the ability to sort rows, filter, etc., and tablesorter works nicely to those ends.  It also maintains consistency, as I use the grid in every other part of the project for things like this.

I have filtering / sorting turned off on the Image column.  

The images are just thumbnails loading as they do on most sites with a list

Comment: I'm not updating the tablesorter to push new data; in fact, I'm not familiar with how its cache works, so that might be part of the problem.  I'm also not using any custom parsing.

Comment: Well if you have the sort disabled and you're not using the filter, then there is no need to update the cache ;) So, the ajax is or isn't working? If you add a console.log for the data, does that show up? Or since you can't get the console on the iPad, maybe just use alert (once) to test it?

Comment: It doesn't appear that the ajax is working in this case b/c I'm not getting any extra HTML after it finishes; the td element is still empty.  This may be a good opportunity to go in and test, however, b/c the warehouse they store inventory in has recently been flooded, so I should be able to go directly into Production and try some things out since the site is down.